# Foreach loop only works inside wordpress loop, but echoes 6 times. Can I use it outside the loop?

Tags: wordpress, foreach, custom-post-type

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'category');  
            foreach ($terms as $term) {  
            $termcomp = $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id; } ?>


            <?php the_field('tagline' , $termcomp); ?>
```

How Can I use this code on wordpress without it echoing 6 times, because I have 6 posts inside that category..

http://pastebin.com/ijqwA5SK

Full page template is there, the foreach is also at the bottom, this one works fine and only outputs once as needed.

Comment: This would be the expected behavior... if there are 6 posts in the `Loop` then you would expect the tags to be posted 6 times. Notice that the terms are fetched using `$post->ID` which is specific to the `$post` that is loaded per loop.

Comment: Can I fetch the terms using something else?

Comment: Which terms? The terms are specific to the post, which is changing on each iteration of the loop, it sounds like you just happen to have the same terms on each post. Can you show an example of the output you see and what you want?

Comment: I think there might be some confusion here... a custom field is a meta field on a post, and a term/tag is a taxonomy applied to a post (which is why the function is called `wp_get_post_terms` and takes the `$post_ID` as an argument). Neither are applied to categories, because not all posts in a category are guaranteed to have the same meta fields or terms. You could show just the terms of the first post, or all of the terms applied to all of the posts... are either of those what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think that is the correct image... ACF is just a wrapper for post meta data... it is not applied to categories. `the_field()` either uses the current `$post_ID` or takes the ID of another post as the second argument.

Comment: That certainly isnt the right image!! I'm sorry about that! http://cl.ly/image/1K3L3U2p1l2h

Comment: Just be clear, you have applied a custom field to your category taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Advanced Custom Fields, you can get the field for a category taxonomy custom field using the `get_field('field', 'category_'.$cat_id)`, or `the_field()` if you want to echo the results automatically. In your case, you first need to determine the current category id, and then call `the_field()` using it for your desired field name, `tagline`. This should be loaded outside of the `Loop`:

```
// only show on category pages
if(is_category()){
    global $wp_query;
    // get category id from query variables
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
    the_field('tagline', 'category_'.$cat_ID);
}
```

Comment: @BenjiSmalley great - just to be clear, assuming a prefix of `wp_`, these values are stored in `wp_options`, not in `wp_postmeta` like real post meta fields. This functionality is only supported by Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: I've found Advanced Custom Fields to be an amazing plugin, it's only downfall is retrieving the fields sometimes like this! Other than that absolutely sterling effort on their part! Lucky there is people like you to know what they're upto!

Comment: I use ACF on all my sites and wrote a wrapper add-on field to do validation that is in the Wordpress repository :)